Unable to set DB flag to check if app was launched for first time or not
i have pre-populated a db with an int value -1 to indicate first time launch of an app and whose value will be changed upon clicking a button to 1. This is basically the DB flag. But i am unable to read the value and update it as well the value being read is null and yes the schema is the same any help or insights and references would be helpful
MainActivity
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val firstTimeViewModel: FirstTimeViewModel = viewModel()
            val isFirstTimeLaunch = firstTimeViewModel.isFirstTimeLaunch
            if(isFirstTimeLaunch.value?.isFirstTime == -1){
                Column (
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
                ) {
                    Text(text ="The app was launched for first time")
                    Spacer(Modifier.height(16.dp))
                    Button(onClick = {
                        firstTimeViewModel.updateIsFirstTimeLaunch(FirstTime(1))
                    }) {
                        Text(text = "update db value")
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(isFirstTimeLaunch.value?.isFirstTime == 1){
                Text(text = "FirstTime launch is over")
            }
        }
    }
}

FirstTimeViewModel
class FirstTimeViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    val isFirstTimeLaunch : LiveData<FirstTime>
    private val repository: FirstTimeRepository

    init {
        val firstTimeDao = PassLockDB.getDatabase(application).FirstTimeDao()
        repository = FirstTimeRepository(firstTimeDao)
        isFirstTimeLaunch = repository.readIsFirstTime
    }

    fun updateIsFirstTimeLaunch(isFirstTime: FirstTime){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repository.updateIsFirstTime(isFirstTime)
        }
    }
    
}


FirstTimeRepository
class FirstTimeRepository(private val firstTimeDao: FirstTimeDao) {

    val readIsFirstTime: LiveData<FirstTime> = firstTimeDao.isFirstTimeLaunch()

    suspend fun updateIsFirstTime(firstTime:FirstTime){
        firstTimeDao.updateFirstTime(firstTime)
    }
}


FirstTimeDao
@Dao
interface FirstTimeDao {

    @Update
    suspend fun updateFirstTime(firstTime: FirstTime)

    @Query("SELECT *from FirstTimeLaunch")
    fun isFirstTimeLaunch(): LiveData<FirstTime>
}

Database
@Database(entities = [FirstTime::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class PassLockDB : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun FirstTimeDao(): FirstTimeDao
    companion object{
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: PassLockDB? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context): PassLockDB {
            val tempInstance = INSTANCE
            if (tempInstance != null) {
                return tempInstance
            }
            synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    PassLockDB::class.java,
                    "FirstTimeLaunch"
                ).createFromAsset("Database/FirstTimeLaunch").build()
                INSTANCE =
                    instance // use singleton , a single instance of database is very efficient
                return instance
            }
        }
    }
}

Entity
@Entity (tableName = "FirstTimeLaunch")
data class FirstTime(
    @PrimaryKey
    val isFirstTime: Int
)


The above code is what i have tried but it doesn't seem to work as intended which is re-composition of ui once db is updated and db fetching of pre-populated data which is -1

There are several problems with your code.
In your Compose UI you have this:
val isFirstTimeLaunch = firstTimeViewModel.isFirstTimeLaunch

On first composition the LiveData isFirstTimeLaunch is retrieved and evaluated. Since this is at the start of your app, it is still null. You only display anything if it is either -1 or 1, so nothing is displayed. So far so good. Now, after some time the data is loaded from the database and the value of isFirstTimeLaunch becomes -1. Compose however already displayed the UI, and Compose doesn't observe the LiveData value for changes by default so the UI is not updated. You have to tell Compose explicitly to watch for changes of the LiveData like this:
val isFirstTimeLaunch by firstTimeViewModel.isFirstTimeLaunch.observeAsState()

This variable is now of type FirstTime? so your next line shoould look something like this:
if (isFirstTimeLaunch?.isFirstTime == -1) {

This will take care of your first problem that the UI didn't respond to the contents of your database.
The next problem is that if you click the now visible button "update db value", nothing happens. Neither now nor on app restart. It doesn't even change anything in the database.
The reason for that is how you define the FirstTime entity:
@Entity(tableName = "FirstTimeLaunch")
data class FirstTime(
    @PrimaryKey
    val isFirstTime: Int,
)

This defines a database table named FirstTimeLaunch. A database table consists of rows and columns, just like a spread sheet. You define one column for your table, the column
isFirstTime. A row is a set of values for each column. Since you only have one column, a row here consists only of a single value. Usually no rows are present at the beginning, but you start with a pre-populated database that provides one row, with a value of -1 for isFirstTime.
So far so good. The issue at hand is that you declared isFirstTime as the primary key of that table. A primary key is used to uniquely identify a row in a table. Primary keys are not supposed to change for a given row. The updateFirstTime function of your DAO assumes this behavior:
@Update
suspend fun updateFirstTime(firstTime: FirstTime)

This will take the provided FirstTime object and finds the row in the database according to the primary key. It then updates the other columns in this row with the values found in the provided FirstTime. Now there is a problem: The provided FirstTime has its isFirstTime property set to 1. So the first step, finding the row in the database, fails. There is no row with isFirstTime == 1 that can be updated, there is just one row with isFirstTime set to -1. The update is just skipped and nothing changes in the database.
How you want it to work is not how databases work. They do not store single values, they store tabular data.
If you only want to store simple key/value pairs like isFirstTime/-1, a DataStore would be better suited.
Since you already have a fully fledged database set up, you can also continue with it. You have to do some changes, though. One option would be just to change updateFirstTime in your DAO to this:
@Query("UPDATE FirstTimeLaunch SET isFirstTime = :isFirstTime")
suspend fun updateFirstTime(isFirstTime: Int)

You won't pass an entire FirstTime object anymore, just the value for isFirstTime. Also, we now use an explicit SQL query to update the database. In this case, all rows in the table are updated. Although there is just one, this skips the need to identify a specific row which was the cause for your initial problem.
Although it works, this is a bit dirty since it's not how databases are supposed to be used. You could make your table to a list of settings where each row would represent a setting with two columns, a name and a value. You would only be able to store settings of the same type, though (in this case, Int). For a clean solution I would actually advise against using a database to store settings at all and recommend a DataStore instead as mentioned above.

i thought about data store , but in the docs itself its mentioned
"Note: If you need to support large or complex datasets, partial updates, or referential integrity, consider using Room instead of DataStore. DataStore is ideal for small, simple datasets and does not support partial updates or referential integrity." so i assumed maybe room is better. Thanks a lot for your detailed explanation ! i will get back on this when i try it out !

You don't have "large or complex datasets" though, on the contrary: You just want to store a single value. You also don't need "partial updates, or referential integrity". But: "DataStore is ideal for small, simple datasets", exactly your use case. It's about what is better suited for your needs. DataStore and Room are both good, they just focus on different aspects.

Hey i have modified it as per DataStore mechanism if possible review it here : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/291814/logic-to-check-if-app-was-launched-for-the-first-time-using-datastore
