Jetpack Compose navigation library problem - conditional navigation
Basically, the problem I'm dealing with is that I have two screens: OnBoarding and login. When the user installs and opens the app for the first time I save true to indicate that it was the first time.
When the user opens the app more than once, it's intended to send them to the login screen, but first shows the onboarding screen for a few seconds and then navigates to the login screen, see the code below:
@Composable
fun Navigation() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    val onBoardingViewModel = hiltViewModel<OnBoardingViewModel>()
    val isTheFirstTimeInstalled = onBoardingViewModel.onBoardingState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    val startDest = getStartDest(isTheFirstTimeInstalled.value)
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = startDest,
        enterTransition = { slideIn() },
        exitTransition = { slideOut() },
    ) { /* some code */ }
}

OnBoardingViewModel:
@HiltViewModel
class OnBoardingViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val dataStore: PreferencesDatastore
) : ViewModel() {
    private val _onBoardingState = MutableStateFlow(false)
    val onBoardingState = _onBoardingState.asStateFlow()

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            _onBoardingState.value = dataStore.getOnBoardingState().first()
        }
    }

    fun setFirstTimeInstalled() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            dataStore.saveOnBoardingState(true)
        }
    }
}

Is there any way to solve this problem? Let me know please!
I only tried to determine the start destination by calling my function "getStartDest" which basically gets the route

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78361380/unable-to-set-db-flag-to-check-if-app-was-launched-for-first-time-or-not and the follow-up https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/291814/logic-to-check-if-app-was-launched-for-the-first-time-using-datastore where your specific problem is discussed in the comments of the answer.

The problem is that you have actually three cases:

Opened for the first time
Not opened for the first time
Undetermined

The third one occurs when the data store hasn't provided a value yet. You can use a Splashscreen to pass the time so neither the OnBoarding nor the Login screen is displayed. It could even be as simple as just displaying a CircularProgressIndicator().
Now, for this to work your view model should already incorporate these three cases. The easiest way to do it would be this:
val onBoardingState: StateFlow<Boolean?> = dataStore.getOnBoardingState()
    .stateIn(
        scope = viewModelScope,
        started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5_000),
        initialValue = null,
    )

The MutableStateFlow and the init block aren't needed anymore, instead the data store flow is directly returned as a StateFlow with initialValue = null. As you can see, the type is now a Boolean? that is nullable. This allows you to differentiate the third case, 3. Undetermined: The StateFlow immediately has a value (null), even when the underlying flow from the data store does not.
As a side note: Please don't collect flows in the view model (as you did with the first() function). Flows should only be collected where they are needed, that is the UI. Everything in between should only be transformations, as shown above.
Now you just need to update getStartDest to also handle the case null (Splashscreen, CircularProgressIndicator, whatever) and you're set.

When using conditional navigation, it is important to note that Onboarding or Login screens are not your start destinations. Your main content (HomeScreen) is the start destination. Put HomeScreen as your start destination and in your HomeScreenRoute, check if you want to navigate to LoginRoute or OnboardingRoute or proceed with showing the HomeScreen content.
@Composable
fun Navigation() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = "home",
        enterTransition = { slideIn() },
        exitTransition = { slideOut() }
    ) {
        homeRoute(
            navigateToOnboarding = { navController.navigate("onboarding") },
            navigateToLogin = { navController.navigate("login") } 
        )
        loginRoute(onLoggedIn = { navController.popBackStack() } )
        onboardingRoute(navigateBackToHome = { navController.popBackStack() } )
    }
}

fun NavGraphBuilder.homeRoute(navigateToOnboarding: () -> Unit, navigateToLogin: () -> Unit) {
    composable(route = "home") {
        HomeRoute(navigateToOnboarding = navigateToOnboarding, navigateToLogin = navigateToLogin) // or your route
    }
}



fun NavGraphBuilder.loginRoute(onLoggedIn : () -> Unit) {
    composable(route = "login") {
        // your route
    }
}



fun NavGraphBuilder.onboardingRoute(navigateBackToHome: () -> Unit) {
    composable(route = "onboarding") {
        // your route
    }
}

Inside your HomeRoute function:
@Composable
internal fun HomeRoute(
    viewModel: HomeViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
    navigateToOnboarding: () -> Unit,
    navigateToLogin: () -> Unit
) {
    val uiState by viewModel.uiState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

    HomeScreen(
        uiState = uiState,
        navigateToOnboarding = navigateToOnboarding,
        navigateToLogin = navigateToLogin
    )
}

@Composable
internal fun HomeScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    uiState: HomeUiState,
    navigateToOnboarding: () -> Unit,
    navigateToLogin: () -> Unit
) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    ) {
        when (uiState) {
            HomeUiState.Loading -> {
                OverlayLoadingWheel(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
                        .padding(top = 8.dp),
                    contentDesc = "Loading"
                )
            }

            is HomeUiState.Success -> {
                when (uiState.hasOnboarded) {
                    true -> HomeClockLayout(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                        uiState = uiState
                    )

                    false -> {
                        LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) {
                            navigateToOnboarding.invoke()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Also, for creating a state inside viewmodels, it's a good practice to avoid running code inside your init block, to make code more "test-friendly".
@HiltViewModel
class HomeViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val appPreferences: AppPreferences
) : ViewModel() {

    val state : StateFlow<HomeUiState> = appPreferences.userData
        .map { preferences ->
            HomeUiState.Success(
                hasOnboarded = preferences.onboardingCompleted,
                isLoggedIn = preferences.isLoggedIn // Or whichever method you're using to check for login
            )
        }
        .stateIn(
            scope = viewModelScope,
            started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5_000),
            initialValue = HomeUiState.Loading
        ) 
             
}

sealed interface HomeUiState {
   data object Loading: HomeUiState
   data class Success(
      val hasOnboarded: Boolean, val isLoggedIn: Boolean,
      // rest of your uiState variables
   )
}


This just unnecessarily complicates matters by introducing another screen, new state objects and by hiding the actually solution in the last code block without even explaining it: The problem was that the MutableStateFlow incorrectly returned false as its first value in a situation where the data store hasn't had yet a chance to retrieve the actual value (false or true). You solved that by returning HomeUiState.Loading instead. While this works (and in general is the preferred way), this is all unnecessary to solve the problem. See my answer for a condensed version.
